# C# - Login system doesen't work

Tags: c#

I'm really not by any means good at developing in C#, and I've just installed VS15 and I've tried something a little more advanced for me where a password would be required to enter the actual core program. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the password:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine;
            if input = rekt();
                Console.WriteLine("You entered the correct password!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("You entered incorrect password!");

        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me fix it? I get into trouble at the "if" part, TBH I don't even know how to end the line itself. Can someone please guide me as a newbie? I did not mean to make anyone angry or annoyed, please.
Thanks so much for any answers. I know you guys are probably busy.

Comment: What is `rekt()`? Is it some method returning string?

Comment: You need to read about how to use the if statement : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx

Comment: Have a look on the net about how to use the if statement. I appreciate that you are trying to learn, but you should absolutely do research before posting a question

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `rekt()` is  method that returns a string containing the correct password, the correct code would be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the password:");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == rekt())
    Console.WriteLine("You entered the correct password!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("You entered incorrect password!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

You don't need to end the line of the correct password with any special character, as `ReadLine()` just returns the actual line, without the 'end line' character.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you cant write this

```cs
string input = Console.ReadLine;
```

The correct code would be

```cs
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

And, if you have a function called `rekt` that returns a string, your if should be like this

```cs
if (input == rekt())
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if(input.Equals(rekt())` be correct due to string comparison?

Comment: It's the same, just a little more performant `Equals` but this users is new and I give simple answer

Answer (score -1):

The condition part of the if statement needs to be surrounded with patentheses.

Another thing to point out is that the equality operator is *==*, just ont *=* is the assignement operator so it means you are assigning the value returning from reckt() to input, not comparing it.

You dont need the semicolon either.

So the if statement in your case will look something like this:
    if(input == reckt())

One last point, ReadLine is a method, so you'll also need to add parentheses when calling it: Console.ReadLine();